# c++ program gets segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I've been working on some coding and I ran into a segmentation fault. I've tried my best to make it work but I kept failing. Now I am asking for help. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ_";

    int sim, a = 0;

    sim = symbols.size();

    string temp[sim];

    while(sim > 0)
    {
    sim--;

    temp[sim] = symbols.substr(sim, 1);

    cout << temp[sim] << endl;
    }

}
```

Well this kinda works but if I do some changes it crashes.

I change:

```
    while(sim > 0)
    {
    sim--;

    temp[sim] = symbols.substr(sim, 1);

    cout << temp[sim] << endl;
    }
```

To this:

```
    while(a < sim)
    {
    a++;

    temp[a] = symbols.substr(a, 1);

    cout << temp[a] << endl;
    }
```

I get SIGFAULT, I don't really understand that is wrong. I used debugger and it doesn't really show at which line it crashes, it just show this:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

In `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int volatile *, int) () ()`

Comment: Do you know at what point in the program its crashing? (the first time it tries to run, at the end, etc)

Comment: Just for correctness's sake, it's spelled "segfault".  Short for "segmentation fault".  SIGwhatever has a particular meaning -- namely, it tends to be a constant whose value represents the signal.  In this case, that's spelled "SIGSEGV".  One or the other is appropriate, but ya kinda gotta pick one.

Comment: cHao -> Okay I'll do it right next time...

Thanks for soliution, I moved a++; to the end of loop and it works fine, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Think what happens when `a == sim-1`- you immediately increment it, so it becomes `sim`, and then access `temp[a]`, although `temp` has valid indexes `0` to `sim-1`.

I suggest you ditch language extensions - namely VLA's - and use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When `a == sim-1` it will re-enter the `while` loop, increment `a` at `a++` so that `a == sim` and then it will crash when trying to access `temp[a]`.

You can fix this by incrementing `a` at the end of the while loop instead of the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your a in temp[a] will got as an index from 1 to sim (inclusive). temp array has sim elements which means valid indexes for thay array are from 0 to sim-1 inclusive.

Move you a++; to be the last statement in while loop and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's clear with temp[a], a more subtle issue is that substr(a, 1) in case a == sym will return empty string which you assign to temp[a]. This probably doesn't cause the crash, but still is an error.